# Save RealityView orientation after RotateGesture3D Interaction

Tags: swiftui, realitykit, visionos

I am trying to rotate a RealityView in 3D space using [RotateGesture3D](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/rotategesture3d). The following code works but the orientation is always reset to the initial rotation the next time I try to rotate the model:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var entity = Entity()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RealityView { content in
                if let scene = try? await Entity(named: "Scene", in: realityKitContentBundle) {
                    entity = scene
                    content.add(scene)
                }
            }
            .gesture(RotateGesture3D().targetedToAnyEntity().onChanged{ value in
                value.entity.orientation = value.convert(value.gestureValue.rotation, from: .local, to: entity.parent!)
            })
        }}
}
```

I have similar code for translating an object in 3D space and it does NOT reset the position between gestures:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent


struct TranslateView: View {
    
    @State var entity = Entity()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RealityView { content in
                // Add the initial RealityKit content
                if let scene = try? await Entity(named: "Scene", in: realityKitContentBundle) {
                    entity = scene
                    content.add(scene)
                }
            }
            .gesture(DragGesture().targetedToAnyEntity().onChanged{value in
                
                var vectorDouble = value.translation3D
                
                // Convert to SIMD3<Float>
                let vectorFloat = SIMD3<Float>(Float(vectorDouble.x/10000), Float(vectorDouble.y/10000), Float(vectorDouble.z/10000))
                
                value.entity.position = value.convert(value.location3D, from: .local, to: entity.parent!)
            })
        }}
}
```

Why does `position` get preserved between gestures while `orientation` does not?

Answer (score 1):

#### RotateGesture3D

First of all, you are not rotating/moving the RealityView itself, but the model in RealityView. Secondly, you need to store the intermediate value for the 3D rotation in a separate variable. And remember, rotation matrices must be [multiplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67896352/realitykit-transform-rotate-makes-object-bigger-in-scale/67897567#67897567), not added.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var entity = Entity()
    @State var rotation: Rotation3D = .identity
    
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            guard let scene = try? await Entity(named: "Scene", in: rkcb),
                  let skull = scene.findEntity(named: "Skull") as? ModelEntity
            else { return }
            content.add(skull)
                
            skull.scale = [5, 5, 5]
            skull.position = [0, 1,-2]
            skull.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
            skull.components[InputTargetComponent.self] = .init()
            entity = skull
        }
        .gesture(
            RotateGesture3D()
                .targetedToAnyEntity()
                .onChanged { value in
                    value.entity.orientation = value.convert(
                                                    value.rotation * rotation,
                                                    from: .local,
                                                    to: entity.parent!)
                }
                .onEnded { value in
                    rotation *= value.rotation
                }
        )         
    }
}
```